# OneNote 2016 can't login for Notebook sync

Tags: sync, login, microsoft-onenote-2016

I have had problems using OneNote 2016 desktop app for a few days recently. My shared notebooks were not properly synced online, presumably due to me not being logged in. The program has indeed asked me for my login credentials.

However, even though I have used the correct username and password, it did not seem to remedy the issue, as if the login attempts were completely futile. Restarting Windows did not help as well. How can the problem be remedied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to remedy the issue by using the method adapted from [this forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-log-in-to-onedrive-from-onenote-2016/60c2a7d1-1677-44a4-8dbf-21f70792cec2). The solution was to:

- open regedit
- go to [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet] (note that the link above uses the 15.0 register branch, worked with 16.0 for me though).
- add new dword 32 bit value named UseOnlineContent and set it to 1
- restart the system

As a sidenote I must say I am amazed by the lengths the user has to go to fix this piece of software though...

Comment: Worked for me! Indeed amazing.